# Shipping Methods in backend returns blank page

Tags: shipping-methods

whenever I try to customize my shipping methods it returns a blank page and I can't really do anything.

I tried flushing my cache of course but that didn't work. Do you have any idea to solve that?

**EDIT:** checked my `system.log` and found this:

> 2015-07-15T20:54:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home2/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2015-07-15T20:54:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home2/dbname/public_html/app/code/local:/home2/dbname/public_html/app/code/community:/home2/dbname/public_html/app/code/core:/home2/dbname/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home2/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: Check exception and system log

Comment: Customizing shipping methods can mean so many things. What exactly are you doing? Accessing the Shipping Method Configuration which gives you a blank page? Being able to access the config, but it gives you a blank page after attempting to save? Hitting the shipping method part of the cart and it gives you a blank page?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR I checked them and edited my original post

Comment: @FiascoLabs I meant trying to access the shipping method which gives me a blank page

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently installed any new extensions? Do you have any extensions related to shipping?

Anything in your logs?

I would start with flushing cache/re-run compilation then logging back in.

Comment: I checked my system.log and put some new infos in original post